# perl system call not executing randomly

Tags: perl, exec

Within a loop construct of a perl script, I have written the following lines to parse text files using system tools, generating temporary text files in the process, and subsequently read the temporary output into an array for processing within the perl script:

```
system("awk '(NR+2)%4==0' $infile[$i+$j] | tre-agrep -ns -E $dist[$a][$b] -k $query[$a][$b] | awk 'BEGIN{FS=\":\";OFS=\":\"}{print \$1,\$2}' > $outfile");
open(my $FH, "<", $outfile) || die "Can't open $outfile: $!";
while(<$FH>) {
  ...
}
close($FH);
```

These commands are repeated twice nearly verbatim (with modification of some of the parameters, but recycling of the file handle) within a loop construct that itself is iterated numerous times. Unexpectedly and seemingly arbitrarily, the program sometimes fails to complete the system call, causing the subsequent lines, which depend on the output generated by the system call, to fail in turn, triggering abortion of the script and display of the rather unhelpful error message "No such file or directory" (with reference to the `open` statement). Executing the same system call directly from a console rather than within the context of the perl script shows that the command produces the expected output. I refer to this behavior as arbitrary because sometimes my script will variously complete 1 to 3 iterations before failing at the `open` line, and the basis for the varying success is not clear. When the script is working properly, the system call takes quite some time (around 2 minutes), whereas when it fails, the program moves to the following `open` line in less than a second. I would thus like to figure out why the system call is sometimes skipped.

The script is run in a bash shell session and the following are included in the script header:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
```

Comment: There's generally no need to call `awk` inside Perl; Perl can do most anything that `awk` can do, and writing native Perl code will help you avoid `system()` and nasty shell quoting issues.

Comment: See: [the XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378). There's a number of things that could be going wrong here; I suspect the variables being interpolated could contain unescaped spaces/metacharacters. If system() really is at fault, dropping in `IPC::System::Simple` will do all the necessary diagnostics for you . I highly recommend editing the question with information about the nature of the problem you're attempting to solve though. Like TheSuitIsBlackNot said, a pure Perl solution would be simpler and more robust than what you're doing now. `Text::Fuzzy` can replace agrep here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fundamentally agree with @ThisSuitIsBlackNot.  However, not knowing what `tre-agrep` is, it's difficult to translate that part into straight Perl.

That said, at the very least, why not skip the generation of the output file and just read the Unix output directly from Perl?

```
open my $FH, '-|', "awk '(NR+2)%4==0' $infile[$i+$j] | " .
    "tre-agrep -ns -E $dist[$a][$b] -k $query[$a][$b]" or die "$!";
while (<$FH>) {
  chomp;
  my ($field1, $field2) = split /:/, $_, 2;
}
close $FH;
```

At worst, the standard output from your system call would be blank, but this wouldn't impact Perl's ability to read nothing (and therefore do nothing).

Of course, it wouldn't hurt to first execute an `-e` (exists) call to be sure that `infile[$i + $j]` isn't a ghost.

Comment: Thanks, I did not realize that one could use a pipe in the open statement in that fashion. That obviates the need for an intermediate file as you have noted, and the `open` statement you have proposed has resolved the problem I mentioned in my original question. However, when the program re-enters the loop and tries to open a new pipe with the file handle `$FH`, the program closes with the error "Cannot allocate memory" (referring to the line containing the `open` statement). Do you have any suggestion on how to resolve this issue? Thank you!

Comment: PS: the `tre-agrep` command is an open-source implementation of approximate grep (`agrep`), which allows approximate pattern matching (matching based on parameterized edit distance or Levenshtein measure).

Comment: That's likely an error with the system call.  How big are the files, and do you have a decent amount of space allocated for swap?

Comment: Actually, the memory allocation problem is unrelated. It is simply the fact that the size of the array used in the program (roughly 2 million by 2x2x2) was too large. Thus, everything now appears to work satisfactorily. Thanks for your help.

Comment: We posted our comments at the exact same time. Yes, the problem was simply exceeding my available system memory (4 GB RAM, 4 GB swap) because of the size of the array generated in the previous step (I initialize a large array with zeroes), though I am a bit surprised that an array comprising 16 million elements requires more than 8 GB of memory (the baseline utilization of my system memory is low so nearly all is available to the script). I will look into whether the array can be typecast to 8-bit integer in order to reduce the memory footprint of the script.

Comment: For what it's worth, once upon a time I was on an AIX system that limited my headroom to 256 MB (or so).  I (unnecessarily) learned memory saving tips.  One thing I learned was that `$array[$one . $two]` takes up less memory than `$array[$one][$two]`.  You need a delimiter, typically, of course.  Same is true for hashes.  It's a pain to de-reference, but if you're just doing lookups, it may save some space.  That said, 4GB does notionally sound sufficient to handle the data volume you're realing with.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Interesting that the delimited 1D array requires less space than the 2D array.